# How secure is demonsaw?

Tags: encryption, http, server

So [Demonsaw](https://demonsaw.com/) 4.0 "Titan" was released a few days ago, it claims that it

> is an encrypted communications platform that allows you to chat,
>   message, and transfer files without fear of data collection or
>   surveillance from governments or corporations.

Here is the [Defcon 22 Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMfQQoHHLBA) explaining what it is.

- How secure is the crypto layer in demonsaw? So far, all I know is that it uses "[demoncrypt](https://github.com/eijah/demoncrypt)".
- Are the default settings of the "customized crypto" secure enough? What would it take to defeat these default settings?

[image: Default Demonsaw crypto settings]

- Demonsaw uses "routers" to transfer messages between clients, but claims that the message itself is encrypted therefor can not be read by the router. Couldn't a malicious router monitor all traffic between the clients and decrypt them?
- How does encryption work over HTTP?
- What is "social crypto"?

Comment: "how secure is X?" is not on-topic question form here; how to break a system requires code review; how encryption 'works' over a channel is too undefined of a question to answer; top hit on Google for "social crypto": https://techcrunch.com/2015/08/19/demonsaw-uses-social-cryptography-to-share-files-and-data-anonymously/